# Proving two different sets are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

> Let $f_{n}, n \geq 1$ and $f$ be measurable functions on a measurable
>   space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Show that the set $\{\omega :
>  \lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(\omega)$ exists $\}$ is
>   $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

I know how to show the set $\{\omega : \lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(\omega) = f(\omega)\}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, and this problem appears to be very similar to that one. But something seems to not be clicking for me to be able to solve this problem. Here is the solution to the other set being $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, which may help with this problem: [Proving a set is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393270/proving-a-set-is-mathcalf-measurable)

I'm really not so sure how to deal with this notion of existence rather than convergence. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that the limit exists if and only if the limsup and liminf are equal. Use the measurability of those functions to write the set you’re looking for (use the fact that sums/differences of measurable functions are measurable).

Comment: So let $g = \limsup_{n} f_{n}$ and $h = \liminf_{n} f_{n}$, and their difference converges to $0$?

Comment: These are unambiguously defined, there’s no convergence. Just take the preimage of zero.

Comment: I'm sort of struggling to understand what you mean by taking the preimage of $0$. As of now, I'm trying to write it as the countable union/intersections of measurable sets.

Comment: $g$ and $h$ are measurable, hence so is $g-h$. This function is equal to zero precisely where the limit of the $f_n$ exists by definition of limit. So your desired set is the preimage of $g-h$ of the set $\{0\}$. Why is this now measurable?

Comment: I've been trying to write the set as something like $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \{\omega \mid g(\omega) - h(\omega) < 1/k\}$. Is this right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments there is the answer in your problem in one-two lines.

If you want a solution with unions and intersections of sets,your way,then:

Let $x_0 \in X$

If $\lim_nf_n(x_0)$ exists then the sequence $f_n(x_0)$ is Cauchy and vice versa (if we assume that $f$ is real valued or complex valued).

Now you can easily see that.

$$\{x: \lim_nf_n(x) \text{ exists }\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n,p \geq m}\{x:|f_n(x)-f_p(x)|<\frac{1}{k}\}$$

which is measurable as countable set  theoretic operations of measurable sets.